# How to show each element of array separately

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a socket that take 60 numbers from another computer in 6 columns and 10 rows. I orderd them with spilit and output is completely right. about first column, I want to take each number separately for calculating moving average filter on them.

Codes:

```
import socket
import numpy as np

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('192.168.0.1', 2015))

column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = []
column4 = []
column5 = []
column6 = []
for message in range(10):
    message = sock.recv(1024)

    a1 = column1.append(message.split()[0])
    a2 = column2.append(message.split()[1]) 
    a3 = column3.append(message.split()[2])
    a4 = column4.append(message.split()[3])
    a5 = column5.append(message.split()[4]) 
    a6 = column6.append(message.split()[5])

    b1 =message.split()[0]
    b2 = message.split()[1]
    b3 = message.split()[2]
    b4 = message.split()[3]
    b5 = message.split()[4]
    b6 = message.split()[5]
    print b1
    print b2
    print b3
    print b4
    print b5
    print b6
```

if I only print b1, output will be 10 numbers that I want to have tham separately for next function (moving average filter). I need help to make them separate.

I tried a for loop for  b1[i] but gives me only first digit of b1.

Comment: Please report immediately to the Redundancy Department of Redundancy... and don't you just want e.g. `for number in b1`?

Comment: hahaha.i reported.no

Comment: I would really like to help you, but your English is rather confusing. Maybe you can give us the expected output and the one you receive instead?

Comment: @xsquared when I print b1, result is 10 numbers. how can i only show first number. ?

Comment: Give us also the content of `message`

Comment: @xsquared '2358833
2358833
2358833
2358833
2358833'

Comment: That is only 5 numbers, how can you split that into 6 pieces? This all doesn't make sense. Maybe reformulate your question with a lot more explanations, including why jonrsharpe's answer does not work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to use a list of columns:

```
columns = [[] for _ in range(6)]
```

Then you can split the message into a single list:

```
for message in range(10):
    message = sock.recv(1024)

    splits = message.split(None, 5) # split into six pieces at most
```

which you can then append to the list of lists you created before:

```
    for index, item in enumerate(splits):
        columns[index].append(item)
```

Now if you only wish to print the first of those appended numbers, do

```
print columns[0][0]  # first item of first list
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started. I have created some random data in the format 6 columns by 10 rows. It then splits the raw data into rows, splits each row into columns and then transposes them to get the data per columns.

Each entry in the first column is then displayed with a moving average of the last 3 entries. `deque` is used to implement an efficient mini queue of the last entries to calculate the moving average with.

```
import collections

message = """89 39 59 88 46 1 87 21 2 34
59 40 68 74 29 29 26 30 93 38
84 60 44 98 41 29 8 60 61 83
36 44 56 8 50 94 99 1 30 52
5 27 53 85 67 69 38 67 69 26
92 17 4 13 74 89 30 49 44 20"""

rows = message.splitlines()
data = []

for row in rows:
    data.append(row.split())

columns = zip(*data)
total = 0
moving = collections.deque()

# Display the moving average for the first column
for entry in columns[0]:
    value = int(entry)
    moving.append(value)
    total += value

    if len(moving) > 3:     # Length of moving average
        total -= moving.popleft()

    print "%3d  %.1f" % (value, total/float(len(moving)))
```

For this data, it will display the following output:

```
 89  89.0
 59  74.0
 84  77.3
 36  59.7
  5  41.7
 92  44.3
```

Tested using Python 2.7